# line break at starting of UILabel text

Tags: cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have string to display in `UILabel`, but the `UILabel` isn't displaying the text of the below string.

> string is :  " \n  \n If you are using a corticosteroid medication"

I know `\n` at the start isn't logical but I am getting it from server and hence I can not change it. So is there any way to resolve this issue.

Any way that label displays rest text by adding two line break at start or how can I truncate `\n` if it is in the beginning of string.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use this
NSString *temp=@" \n \n If you are using a corticosteroid medication";
NSString *resultString=[temp stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to remove `\n` from your string you could just use something as simple as

```
NSString *myString = @" \n \n If you are using a corticosteroid medication";

myString  = [[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n"
                                                         withString:@""];
```

`stringByReplacingOccurencesOFString: withString:` will replace all occurrences of the given string (In your case `\n`) with the given string.

The above should technically do the exact same as `[myString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];`

If you want to replace only within a specific range then you could use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` instead like:

```
myString = [myString replaceOccurencesOfString:@"\n" 
                           withString:@"" 
                              options:NULL
                                range:NSMakeRange(0, 7)];
```

This will remove all occurrences of `\n` within the given range, for this example from `0 - 7`
Check out he Apple documentation for this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Comment: Thanks dude. I know this will work. but will this also remove \n if it is in the middle of the string ? I just want to remove if it is at the beginning.

Comment: It will remove all occurrences no matter where they are start, middle or end.

Comment: Yeah. stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet worked very well. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

```
[yourString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *text = @" \n \n If you are using a corticosteroid medication";
text = [text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```